# What makes a process appear as Not responding in Windows?

Tags: windows, process

What is it exactly that "triggers" Windows to mark a process as *Not responding* in the Task Manager and Resource Monitor?

Comment: if (OS == Vista) { DoNotRespond(); }

Comment: lol. +1 for the comment, while I write this on Vista. However, it probably was coded as **if (OS = VISTA) {DoNotRespond();}** :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The API behind this is [IsHungAppWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633526(VS.85).aspx).  Basically, if the application has not pumped a message within 5 seconds it can be marked as not responding.

Answer (score 8):

If a process does not collect **Windows messages** from its queue using the [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28VS.85%29.aspx) function or [something related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943%28VS.85%29.aspx), it will be tagged as "not responding" -- because it is not responding to **user interface events**.

This does not necessarily mean that the application is actually hung -- it may just be too busy to pay attention to the user.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that they don't empty their message queue, by polling it GetMessge API and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it get's it self into a state where the program does not return to a point where it can process it's message queue.

Usually, this is either a loop that doesn't end or a blocking operation, such as reading from a socket, etc.

Comment: Norton Antivirus frequently grabs my browser or my thunderbird email client and locks it into a not-responding.  Its very annoying.

Comment: The amount of issues I have encountered that were caused by Norton products has given me psychological scarring

Comment: thats why you use the new microsoft product or eset nod32 instead ;)